# Adobe CQ5 API Usage

Tags: adobe, aem

1.
I am managing a website which uses Adobe CQ5 as their management system. I am aware that there is a tool `querybuilder.json` in the `/bin` folder -- My question is, if an outside user would use this tool which API-syntax would they use to query "important" or "sensitive information". I need to know this so that I can block access to those syntax strings during GET or POST. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

So, what I'm asking is, if an attacker got access to the query builder link, would he be able to query passwords or internal login's, if so how? And if that, which syntax for the query builder can i remove to provoke this?

2.
Also, would anyone be able to tell me the proper syntax for the adobe querybuilder that can give you the hostname or web location where the directory that it lists is located?

So for example, if I got back `/apps/geometrixx/user/login` as output, I would also want to get the url that this file path is at on my server. Is there a syntax available for this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider disabling all requests to paths starting with `/bin` prefix for your publish instance.

This is a common storage for all servlets that are very useful for authoring but not as much for the other instance.

If you have any custom servlets in the application please take a look at [Apache Sling documentation](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html) and consider using resource based servlets.

```
@SlingServlet(
    resourceTypes = "sling/servlet/default",
    selectors = "hello",
    extensions = "html",
    methods = "GET")
public class MyServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {
```

This way you can control the access to the servlet using ACLs - if you have an access to the node (i.e. you can see it/render a component based on this resource) you will have an access to the servlet.

Answer (score 1):

1. The best way to prevent unauthorized access to tools like this, is to `deny` *.json on your dispatcher and only `allow` calls to your application specific json. A good start what you should do can be found in the [Security Checklist](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/security_checklist.html).
2. A documentation regarding the Query Builder can be found here: http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/search/querybuilder-api.html